# Apache invisible rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm hosting a website for a friend of me and I want to use a sub domain (sapp.xgclan.com) to link to his directory on my webserver.

You can also access this directory by going to www.xgclan.com/sapp/
Now I'm using the following .htaccesses file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sapp.)xgclan.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sapp [L]
```

It works fine but when I visit sapp.xgclan.com it turns it into sapp.xgclan.com/sapp/
I don't want it to visibly add the /sapp/ part to the url in the browser.

I already tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sapp.)xgclan.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sapp [QSA,L]
```

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if its sapp.xgckan.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sapp.xgclan.com$ [NC]
#rewrite the request to the sapp folder
RewriteRule ^ sapp%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

**EDIT**

> I just want to do this for the following sub domains: forum, sapp and servers

For `forum`, `sapp` and `servers` use the solution below instead

```
#if its sapp/forum/servers.xgckan.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sapp|forum|servers).xgclan.com$ [NC]
#rewrite the request to the sap/forum/servers folder
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: That works =)

However the links in my joomla website still have the /sapp/ which makes the url look like: http://sapp.xgclan.com/sapp/downloads

Comment: What I also noticed is that I cant add any extra sub domains, by copying this code.

It generates 500 errors if you use it multiple times.

Comment: @gijs007 Are you looking for a generic rule that will rewrite `any-subdomain.xgclan.com` to `any-subdomain/` ?

Comment: No, because I have a www. subdomain which I might want to use later.

I just want to do this for the following sub domains: forum, sapp and servers

Comment: That works fine, however its still showing the /sapp /forum, etc when you click on a link within the sub domain.

Is it possible to fix that to?

Comment: @gijs007 That is probably because the links are absolute from root i.e. `/sapp/downloads` vs relative `downloads`. The best way to address this would be to make the links relative

Comment: I couldn't find any settings in phpbb or joomla to change the links to relative links.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @gijs007 Sorry, I am not experienced with either

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer to the concrete question, but: Why don't you point the virtual host sapp.xglcan.com directly to the sapp subdirectory? Like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot [path/to/www.xglan.com]/sapp
ServerName sapp.xglan.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I tried using virtual hosts, but it made my main website www.xgclan.com redirect to the sapp website as well...

Comment: Should be an error in virtual host config. I use virtual hosts to run some very primitive CDN by pointing images.example.com to www.exampl.com/images, which is similar to what you are doing.